# Syntax needed to exit a Worksheet_Change for multiple ranges subroutine if more than one target

Tags: vba, excel

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    Dim rngF As Range, rngC As Range
    Dim aCell As Range, bCell As Range
    Dim wkSheet1 As Worksheet

    'recursive error prevention
    On Error GoTo Whoa
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then GoTo Letscontinue

    '___set range
    Set wkSheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("backend")

    Set rngF = wkSheet1.Range("C5:C500,H5:H500,M5:M500,R5:R500,W5:W500,AB5:AB500" & _
              ",AG5:AG500,AL5:AL500,AQ5:AQ500,AV5:AV500,BA5:BA500,BF5:BF500," & _
              "BK5:BK500,BP5:BP500,BU5:BU500,BZ5:BZ500,CE5:CE500,CO5:CO500," & _
              "CT5:CT500,CY5:CY500,DD5:DD500,DI5:DI500,DN5:DN500," & _
              "DS5:DS500,DX5:DX500,EC5:EC500")
    Set rngC = wkSheet1.Range("D5:D500,I5:I500,N5:N500,S5:S500,X5:X500,AC5:AC500," & _
               "AH5:AH500,AM5:AM500,AR5:AR500,AW5:AW500,BB5:BB500,BG5:BG500," & _
               "BL5:BL500,BQ5:BQ500,BV5:BV500,CA5:CA500,CF5:CF500,CP5:CP500," & _
               "CU5:CU500,CZ5:CZ500,DE5:DE500,DJ5:DJ500,DO5:DO500," & _
               "DT5:DT500,DY5:DY500,ED5:ED500")


    'fORECAST

    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, rngF) Is Nothing Then
        '~~> Loop through all cells in the range
        For Each aCell In rngF
            If aCell.Value <> "" Then
                If aCell.Value <> "N/A,TBC,TBA,TBD" Then
                    If aCell.Value < Date Then
                        aCell.ClearContents
                        MsgBox "The Forecast date you have specified " & _
                        "may not occur in the past. Please try again"
                    Else
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If

    'complete

    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, rngC) Is Nothing Then
        '~~> Loop through all cells in the range
        For Each bCell In rngC
            If bCell.Value <> "" Then
                If bCell.Value > Date Then
                    bCell.ClearContents
                    MsgBox "The Forecast date you have specified " & _
                    "may not occur in the past. Please try again"
                Else
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If

Letscontinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Letscontinue
End Sub
```

The question: I used `If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub` to try get the sub to exit as soon as more than 1 cell had been affected. IE: After a single target cell in any of the specific ranges is affected, stop executing the clear cell contents on any others. Im sure my syntax is wrong or the logic needs a tweak. I've omitted part of the code that isn't affected.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 1):

`If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub` is good enough :) However this line can give you error in Excel 2007+

`Target.Cells.Count` returns an `Integer` and it will give you an error in Excel 2007+ if the number of cells affected as they can be of `Long` Type

For Excel 2007+ use the below

```
If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
```

**Note**: You need to add the line before you switch off events. Else instead of `Exit Sub`, you will have to say

```
If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then GoTo LetsContinue
```

Where `LetsContinue` is where you do the clean up as shown [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860894/ms-excel-crashes-when-vba-code-runs/13861640#13861640)

**Example 1**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    '~~> Your code

Letscontinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Letscontinue
End Sub
```

**Example 2**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then GoTo Letscontinue

    '~~> Your code

Letscontinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Letscontinue
End Sub
```

**Followup From Comments**

Ah I think you misunderstood how the _Change Event Fires :) This event will fire if any cell is changed. `Target.Cells.CountLarge` checks for the number of cells that are changed right now. For example if you copy and paste values in say Cell `A1:A5` then it means `5` cells are being changed at the moment.

What you want to do is run a piece of code when the user input a date in the userform. If that is correct then this code is what you need. I am using `Sub Update()` You may have to put it in the CommandButton Code (if you are using that)

Also you do not need to type the entire range. See how I am creating the range using a loop.

**Note**: The below code is Untested.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Update()
    Dim rngF As Range, rngC As Range
    Dim aCell As Range, bCell As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("backend")

    With ws
        '~~> This creates your range
        For i = 3 To 133 Step 5
            If rngF Is Nothing Then
                Set rngF = .Range(ReturnName(i) & "5:" & ReturnName(i) & 500)
            Else
                Set rngF = Union(rngF, .Range(ReturnName(i) & "5:" & ReturnName(i) & 500))
            End If

            If rngC Is Nothing Then
                Set rngC = .Range(ReturnName(i + 1) & "5:" & ReturnName(i + 1) & 500)
            Else
                Set rngC = Union(rngC, .Range(ReturnName(i + 1) & "5:" & ReturnName(i + 1) & 500))
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    'Debug.Print rngF.Address
    'Debug.Print rngC.Address

    '~~> Forecast
    '~~> Loop through all cells in the range
    For Each aCell In rngF
        If aCell.Value <> "" Then
            If aCell.Value <> "N/A,TBC,TBA,TBD" Then
                '<~~ Is this the date from userform. If yes then 
                '<~~ use a variable and input it below instead of `Date`
                If aCell.Value < Date Then 
                    aCell.ClearContents
                    MsgBox "The Forecast date you have specified " & _
                    "may not occur in the past. Please try again"
                    Exit For '<~~ This will exit the For Loop. To exit the sub use `Exit Sub`
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next

    '~~> Complete
    '~~> Loop through all cells in the range
    For Each bCell In rngC
        If bCell.Value <> "" Then
            '<~~ Is this the date from userform. If yes then 
            '<~~ use a variable and input it below instead of `Date`
            If bCell.Value > Date Then
                bCell.ClearContents
                MsgBox "The Forecast date you have specified " & _
                "may not occur in the past. Please try again"
                Exit For '<~~ This will exit the For Loop. To exit the sub use `Exit Sub`
            Else
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Function ReturnName(ByVal num As Integer) As String
    ReturnName = Split(Cells(, num).Address, "$")(1)
End Function
```

Comment: Siddharth!! Thanks so so so much for you answer! It feels really great to get YOUR answer as it was one of your original answers that I built the code off of. The irony that you answered this is crazy. So for the original, and this update THANKS!! :)

Comment: Thank you for the kind comments :) Yes I know it was based on the code that I wrote. No one actually uses `'~~>` or `Whoa` other than me :D

Comment: Sorry Siddharth,  I tried both examples but the macro still identified and cleared more than the single specific cell i needed to check. Basically I entered in a date yesterday, that gets cleared today when the sub runs...

Comment: @Dylan don't hesitate to accept the answer if it works: it will tell other users with your same problem that this is the solution.

Comment: Thanks Matteo NNZ, it hasnt resolved just yet. I was just excited to get SIddharth's response as his was the code I originally got inspired from

Comment: with the example 2 built in, @SiddharthRout

Comment: @Dylan: I indented your code. I see an EndIf missing. besides that I don't see any problem with the code. Can you explain what were you truing to do and what were you expecting and what results did you actually get?

Comment: @SiddharthRout, essentially I use a userform to input dates into this hidden 'backend' sheet. the inputs go into the specified ranges.As you can see, this sub prevents you from choosing a past date for forecast. If I set a forecast date today, as today's date: ie I input 28/05/2015 now. Then, if I come into the file tommorrow and change any other value, it causes the sub to run and then deletes the 28/05/2015 date i specified yesterday. So i was hoping i could get the sub to run on 1 specific cell, then stop checking the rest, as they may be in the past but that data must be preserved.

Comment: Ah I think you misunderstood how the _Change Event Fires :) This event will fire if any cell is changed. `Target.Cells.CountLarge` checks for the number of cells that are changed right now. For example if you copy and paste values in say Cell A1:A5 then it means 5 cells are being changed at the moment

Comment: @SiddharthRout oh I see! so its the incorrect event for what I am trying to do?? Could you suggest a different Event for this? is there a different type of _change event?

Comment: Yes that would work perfectly! If I can only input into 1 cell at a time, I only need the Sub to run for that 1 cell. then the sub can exit. :)

Comment: @Dylan: I have updated the post. See the section `Followup From Comments` You may have to refresh the page